# Wrapping ScrollView around list of objects in react native

Tags: react-native

the following is a simple code i am trying on react-native, it works fine on simulator except it is hard coded

```
function CardCreator(props) {
const cards = props.cards;
const basicCards = cards.map((c, index) => {
    return <BasicCard key={index} character={c} />
});
// return basicCards;

return (
    <ScrollView>
        {/* code to replace the following */}
        <BasicCard character={cards[0]} />
        ..
        <BasicCard character={cards[9]} />
        {/* returning the basicCards entries here */}
    </ScrollView>
)}
```

I can return `basicCards` object to render() but cannot scroll to see all the items.Currently using the hard coded values to return the expected result.
How can i return the `basicCards` object after wrapping it in `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the hard-coding inside render method, like,

```
render() {
  const { cards } = this.props;
  return (
    <ScrollView>
     {
       cards.map((c, index) => {
         return <BasicCard key={index} character={c} />
       })
     }
    </ScrollView>
  );
 }
```

Just iterate through `cards` and return each individual component.

**OR**

As per your sample code, the changes will be

```
function CardCreator(props) {
  const cards = props.cards;
  const basicCards = cards.map((c, index) => {
      return <BasicCard key={index} character={c} />
  });

return (
   <ScrollView>
     {basicCards}
   </ScrollView>
 )
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: cards.map() throws token exception with the semicolon, otherwise this works, please edit the answer to remove the semicolon. Thanks

Comment: the extra code answered another problem which i was going to ask. Thanks!